# i want to scrape data from website using php

Tags: php, html

scraping perticular data from website using php without using any tools,i have tried this code but it is not sufficient-

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.google.com';

$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: What is not sufficient? Be more specific please.

Comment: What data do you need to scrape?

Answer (score 2):

you can used curl in php

```
<?  
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec(); 
curl_close($ch); 
 ?>
```

where $data contain html of given url